# Hide the selected item of list view

Tags: android, listview

I am working on a video player and I have a custom ListView of images. When I select any image the respective video will play. I want the image whose video is being played to become invisible to the user. When I select another image, it will become invisible and previous one become visible.

Things that I want on select listener to do:

```
1. Hide the selected item from list.
2. After when another element is selected, show the previous one and hide the selected one.
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a global variable to store the selected item of listview

```
private int mItemClicked=-1;
```

When you are clicking a videoview inside the onclick method save the position  the clicked item and call

```
videoView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
   @Override 
   public void onClick(View v) {
       mItemClicked=position; 
       notifyDataSetChanged(); 
     } 
 });
```

Then in the getView method check if the position is already selected or not like this

```
if(mItemClicked==position){ 
     //Hide the list item
}else{
    //Show the list item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the Id or position of the item and add remove that item from list 
And later add that one and remove another one

Thanks

Comment: can you please give me an example like this